# Ребят, прошу, скажите, какие мне языки программирования изучать?

Tags: c#, python, c++, ооп

Ребят, это вопрос, но в основном, дайте совет. Какие языки программирования мне учить: какие и сколько. Мне нравится ООП. Также, хочу стать успешным гейм девом, пока что фиговые игры у меня получаются, но всё же игры. Я не знаю насчёт C++. Стоит ли мне его изучать тоже. Сейчас я изучаю C# и Python. Этого достаточно. Я не думаю, потому что python это мой второй инструмент. Если у меня не получается на C# я использую Python. Не умею делать сайты не на C#, не на Python. Так что ребят, какой мне язык программирования учить в 2020 году, и сколько мне их надо учить. До 18 лет мне больше пяти лет. Мне не нравится Ruby и Java.[image: Индекс тиобе]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109320/discussion-on-question-by-mr-catyt-------).

Answer (score 6):

Не важно что изучать, важно заниматься любимым делом, потому что рано или поздно вас будет вести в перёд только она. Языки, фреймворки или вообще космические технологии это инструменты и если у вас не будет того ради чего вы готовы работать сутки на пролет и поверьте мне это не деньги, то эти инструменты не помогут.

Comment: "только она" — она кто?

Comment: "Золотые слова!"

Comment: Она любимая: работа, жизнь, семья всё то что заставляет терпеть.